# need to write a function to add values based on query in EXCEL

Tags: excel

S.no   Area
1   55
2   65
3   51
4   70
5   55
6   65
7   75
8   60
9   45
10  50
11  70
12  52
13  65
14  40
15  60
16  55
17  50
18  65
19  85
20  81

By entering range of Sno. e.g 3 to 5    I MUST GET THE ADDITION OF **Area** for specified range of Sno.

Note : range of sno. may vary like 3 to 5 , 10 to 18 etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
=SUMIF(A1:A100,"<=5",B1:B100)-SUMIF(A1:A100,"<3",B1:B100)
```

Sum everything less than five, then subtract the sum of everything less than three.  Adjust the range references to fit your data.  Or if you like array formulas

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A100<=5)*(A1:A100>=3)*(B1:B100))
```

does the same thing.

Comment: thnk 4 respons Dick but i have a different issue here
i have dropdown list of S.no. 1 to 20 in two different cells when i select 3 form one cell and 7 from another i should get the result in adjacent cell containing function. 

Note: My selection could vary e.g 10 in one cell and 18 in another & i must get the answer in the same cell containing function.

i appreciate ur response & looking for further solution

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the help for SUMIF.